# How to show a element immediately, such as a loading indicator, with Vue? nextTick isn't working as I expect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I have a Vue component in a .vue file with a data member `isLoading: false`, and a template:

```
<div v-show="isLoading" id="hey" ref="hey">Loading...</div>
<button @click="loadIt()">Load it</button>
```

And a method:

```
loadIt() {
  this.isLoading = true
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    console.log(this.$refs.hey)
    // ...other work here that causes other DOM changes
    this.isLoading = false
  })
}
```

("Loading" here refers to loading from the in-memory store, not an AJAX request.  I want to do this so that I can show a simple "loading" indicator instantly while the DOM changes that might take 0.2-0.5 second or so are occurring.)

I thought that the `$nextTick` function would allow both the virtual and actual DOM to update. The console log reads that the item was "shown" (removing the `display: none` style). However, in both Chrome and Firefox, I never see the "Loading..." indicator; the short delay happens, and the other DOM changes happen without the Loading indicator being shown.

If I use `setTimeout` instead of `$nextTick`, I will see the loading indicator, but only when the other work is sufficiently slow.  If there is a delay of a few tenths of a second, the loading indicator never shows. I'd like it to appear immediately on click so that I can present a snappy GUI.

[Example in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szal/eywraw8t/500316/)

Comment: you could try using v-if instead of v-show

Comment: Tried it; no change.

Comment: Can you demonstrate in a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: Did you try calling `this.$forceUpdate()` immediately after `this.isLoading = true`?

Comment: Fiddle posted.  $forceUpdate() had no effect.

Comment: If you set up a breakpoint on the `console.log(this.$refs.hey)` line you'll see that the loading indicator does show.

Comment: OK, so how do I get it to show without the breakpoint?

Comment: Without this becoming some sort of discussion in comments, IMO you're doing it wrong: https://scotch.io/tutorials/add-loading-indicators-to-your-vuejs-application

Comment: I see you already found the answer. To summarize, the problem lies in a fact that you are (at least in the fiddle) performing an expensive **synchronous** operation which collides with browsers' limitations. A solution is using an asynchronous operation or using web workers for instance. The latter approach is described here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651601/vue-js-loading-indicator-for-computed-property-re-render

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to wrap the long-runing synchronous code so that a DOM update can finish before it.  The documentation for Vue.nextTick says this is what it is for, but it seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [Github 'issue'](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1023) there is some 'funky' business going on with `Vue.nextTick`. It appears that the `nextTick` function actually fires just before the DOM is about to re-render. `nextTick` will be fired before the DOM can show the `loading` div and immediately gets hidden once `nextTick` finishes. There are some suggetions in the Github issue but not all of them work.

The only way they got it to work is if you use `setTimeout` with a delay. Setting the delay to 1 millisecond won't always guarantee a DOM update, so it is suggested to use around 25 milliseconds. I know this isn't really what you wanted but it's all I could find. Hopefully you get some use out of the Github link.

[JSFiddle with examples](https://jsfiddle.net/n9jmu5v7/29718/)

Comment: This answer seems to work.  Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/szal/huLj6kby/2/

Comment: No problem. But I agree with @AlexeySh. it's not really good practice to use these 'magic numbers'. It works, I'll give you that but should there be a better alternative I'd really suggest switching to that

Comment: The issue still exists in Vue3. I also tried to $forceUpdate and it didn't work. But this setTimeout approach works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you're over complicating things.

This appears to work just fine:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   isLoading: false,
   done: false
  },
  methods: {
    loadIt() {
      this.isLoading = true
      // Simulate some long running AJAX request...
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.done = true
        this.isLoading = false
      }, 3000)
    }
  }
})
```

**Edit:** After reading further about your issue, the code below appeared to work for me. It's kind of a hack really. I guess your issue is to do with the event loop?

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   isLoading: false,
   done: false
  },
  methods: {
    loadIt () {
      this.isLoading = true

      window.setTimeout(() => {
        for (var i = 1; i < 40000000; ++i) {
          this.done = !i
        }

        this.done = true
        this.isLoading = false
      }, 10)    
    }
  }
})
```

**Note:** This 100% works but I did notice that JSFiddle is a bit odd with 'saving' and 'running'. Make sure to hit <kbd>Command</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> first and then click the Run button.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that only works because of the setTimeout, and then only if the delay is long enough.  I don't want to simulate an AJAX request, but rather a long-running DOM manipulation.  Without a setTimeout, the indicator never shows; here's a demo of your suggestion where you can see it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/szal/o7ykfrhd/2/

Comment: And here's an example with the work inside a setTimeout that also doesn't work.  https://jsfiddle.net/szal/yk84rbwq/4/

Comment: Great thanks-yes, that is what I had to do.  Seems wrong, and I asked for a fix: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9200 - but I've been shut down.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Please consider marking this as the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in browsers itself. They have lazy approach to rerendering. Intentionally, to protect you from layout thrashing. So you should use a little trick to force the browser to rerender screen immediately:

```
loadIt() {
  this.isLoading = true
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    // You are right here, reference is now
    // available, so far, so good
    console.log(this.$refs.hey)
    // And here the problem lies. Browser is now
    // intentionally waiting for another changes in DOM to
    // batch them, to compute and rerender all changes l
    // So, when you change the visibility now, back to
    // invisible state, browser batch these two changes
    // and it will do it both at once. The result is your
    // component will be not rendered at all. So, here you
    // you should force the browser to rerender screen
    // now, immediately, with, for example, asking it for
    // new element width:
    let width = this.$refs.hey.width
    // Now the browser have no other option, just rerender
    // whole DOM and give you new element width. So, now
    // your component is rendered by browser for sure and
    // you can switch the visibility again:
    this.isLoading = false
  })
}
```

Complete example:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isLoading" ref="hey">
    Loading...
  </div>

  <button @click="loadIt">
    Load it
  </button>

  <div v-if="isDone">
    Done
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',

  data () {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      isDone: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    delay: ms => new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(res, ms)
    }),

    async loadIt() {
      this.isLoading = true

      // wait for vdom -> dom
      await this.$nextTick()

      // force dom rerendering
      console.log(this.$refs.hey.width)

      // wait for some time, higher than monitor refresh rate
      await this.delay(40)

      this.isDone = true
      this.isLoading = false
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: One of us is missing something, as just I tried that and it didn't help: https://jsfiddle.net/szal/bx9docf4/6/ -- I thought your "force" code should go earlier, but that didn't help either: https://jsfiddle.net/szal/djw3crzu/4/

Comment: I'm on smartphone now. Paste your example at jsbin.com instead, jsfiddle is not mobile friendly

Comment: Jsbin doesn't seem to be working right--the `for` loop in my example executes immediately regadless of the number of loops, so I can't find a way to simulate a long in-memory operation.  Please take a look at the jsfiddle if you can.

Answer (score -2):

This is because you are using ***synchronous*** js operation

```
for (var i = 1; i<10000000; ++i){
    this.done = !i
}
```

If you want to get the loading indicator to appear on the page
you have to ***use a web worker*** or change logic to ***asynchronous*** style.

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/508odkm9/1/

Comment: Isn't that what nextTick() is supposed to help with?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski as you can see nextTick works fine - loading message is appearing in the dom (at least you can see it in the console). the browser works in an unexpected manner so you can see it in the dom but it doesn't visible on the page.

Comment: Yes, exactly--I want to get the loading indicator to appear on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I see how that works--yes, that would work if I were invoking code here.  However, my problem is that the slowness happens as a result of reactivity changes elsewhere in the app--other Vue components are reacting to a change to a store value.  Instead of trying to show all that logic here, I am simulating it in a dummy for loop.  How do I wrap that for loop so that the "Loading..." indicator shows in the browser regardless of what comes after it?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski the same approach. your components work synchronously

Comment: Exactly.  If I wrap the sensitive change in a setTimeout with enough delay, then it works.  I guess I'll do that, per T. Dirks.